# Ubuntu 20.04 stuck in airplane mode

Tags: networking, wireless, realtek

I have HP Pavilion laptop model 11-n00ea. I have Windows 10 and dual boot it with Ubuntu. I started with 16.04 then upped to 18.04 and now running 20.04. The wifi works perfectly with Windows 10, but in Ubuntu 20.04 it's stuck in airplane mode and the key to disable this brings up a black box which tells me Hardware Airplane.

I have tried many ways to get this to work including reinstalling the RT3290 driver.

When I plug a wifi USB dongle in however, the airplane button works, but still I cannot turn on wifi for both of the cards. I am wondering if I somehow disable the built in wifi card, I might be able to use a wifi USB dongle?

Output for `sudo nmcli d` :

```
DEVICE    TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION         
enp4s0    ethernet  connected    Wired connection 1 
wlp2s0f0  wifi      unavailable  --                 
lo        loopback  unmanaged    --
```

For sudo rfkill list:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

With USB dongle in:

```
sudo nmcli d
DEVICE           TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION         
enp4s0           ethernet  connected    Wired connection 1 
wlp2s0f0         wifi      unavailable  --                 
wlx1cbfce2300e7  wifi      unavailable  --                 
lo               loopback  unmanaged    --
```

With ethernet unplugged:

```
sudo nmcli d
DEVICE           TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION 
enp4s0           ethernet  unavailable  --         
wlp2s0f0         wifi      unavailable  --         
wlx1cbfce2300e7  wifi      unavailable  --         
lo               loopback  unmanaged    --
```

Clicking on the right-hand top corner arrow gives me:

```
PCI wifi off
Wifi off
```

`sudo rfkill list` with dongle in:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: phy1: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

- I have tried to unblock all to no effect.
- I have reset bios to factory settings to no effect.
- I have blocked hp-wmi to no effect.

Comment: In the wifi settings, as long as the usb wifi dongle is inserted, I have control over the aeroplane button and its F12 on my laptop and it does switch on and off also, as long as the dongle is inserted. However when I try to switch the wifi on it just switches off again.

Comment: as an extra, when the dongle is out I am stuck again with no control over either aeroplane mode or wifi. is there a way todisable the onboard wifi card ( and a way to enable it as I use it for ethernet connection) then see if the usb dongle works?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `dkms status` and `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. Confirm that your model # is, in fact, 11-n00ea.

Comment: I just got the same. Is there any answer to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It turns out that there is a small physical switch on the device that switches WiFi on and off.

Somehow I had activated this switch to "Wifi off"